# Batched elements after shuffling seemingly non-consecutive in TensorFlow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor1 = tf.constant(value = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
tensor2 = tf.constant(value = [20, 21, 22, 23])

print(tensor1.shape)
print(tensor2.shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tensor1, tensor2))

print('Original dataset')
for i in dataset:
      print(i)

dataset = dataset.repeat(3)

print('Repeated dataset')
for i in dataset:
      print(i)
```

It returns, as expected:

```
(4, 3)
(4,)
Original dataset
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=21>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=22>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([10, 11, 12], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=23>)
Repeated dataset
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=21>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=22>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([10, 11, 12], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=23>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=21>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=22>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([10, 11, 12], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=23>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=21>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=22>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([10, 11, 12], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=23>)
```

If I then batch the `dataset` as:

```
dataset = dataset.batch(3)

print('Batched dataset')
for i in dataset:
   print(i)
```

I receive, as expected:

```
Batched dataset
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([20, 21, 22], dtype=int32)>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([23, 20, 21], dtype=int32)>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [ 1,  2,  3]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([22, 23, 20], dtype=int32)>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([21, 22, 23], dtype=int32)>)
```

The batched dataset takes consecutive elements.

However, when I suffle first and then batch as:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(3)

print('Shuffled dataset')
for i in dataset:
  print(i)

dataset = dataset.batch(3)

print('Batched dataset')
for i in dataset:
   print(i)
```

the batched elements are non-consecutive:

```
Shuffled dataset
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=21>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=22>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=22>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([10, 11, 12], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=23>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([10, 11, 12], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=23>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=21>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=22>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=21>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=20>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([10, 11, 12], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=23>)
Batched dataset
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([22, 20, 20], dtype=int32)>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([21, 22, 23], dtype=int32)>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([23, 21, 22], dtype=int32)>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6]], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([23, 20, 21], dtype=int32)>)
```

I'm using Google Colab with `TensorFlow 2.x`.

My question is: ***Why shuffling before batching makes `batch` return non-consecutive elements***?

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should absolutely read this: [tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

It's what shuffling does. You started with this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

You specified `buffer_size=3` so it creates a buffer of the 3 first elements:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

You specified `batch_size=3` so it will pick ONE element randomly from this sample, and replace it with the FIRST element outside the initial buffer. Let's say `[1, 2, 3]` was picked, your batch is now:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

And your buffer is now:

```
[[10, 11, 12], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

For the second element of your `batch=3`, it will pick randomly from this buffer. Let's say `[7, 8, 9]` is picked, your batch is now:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```

And your buffer is now:

```
[[10, 11, 12], [4, 5, 6]]
```

There's nothing new to to fill the buffer, so it will pick randomly one of these elements, say `[10, 11, 12]`. Your batch is now:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

And the next batch will be only `[4, 5, 6]` because as a default,  `batch(drop_remainder=False)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I properly understand, when I execute `dataset = dataset.batch(3)` it executes the whole previous pipeline, including `from_tensor_slices`, `repeat` and `shuffle`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes it's a chain that describes what's gonna happen. It's executed only when you iterate through it

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. +1 and accepted answer.